# Closure Compiler Externs for Function with static fields

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler

What is the correct type for a constructor function that also has properties on the function object with Google's closure compiler?

Here's a runnable first attempt on the [Closure compiler debugger](https://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3Dconst%2520Mocha%2520%253D%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257B!MochaJS%257D%2520*%252F%2520(require('mocha'))%253B%250A%250Aconst%2520mochaInstance%2520%253D%2520new%2520Mocha()%253B%250Aconst%2520Suite%2520%253D%2520Mocha.Suite%253B%250A%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%3D%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540externs%250A%2520*%252F%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540constructor%2520*%252F%250Aconst%2520MochaJS%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257B!MochaJS.Suite%257D%2520*%252F%250AMochaJS.prototype.Suite%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540record%2520*%252F%250AMochaJS.Suite%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520src%250A%2520*%2520%2540return%2520%257B!Object%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520require(src)%2520%257B%257D%250A%26refasterjs-template%26includeDefaultExterns%3D1%26CHECK_SYMBOLS%3D1%26MISSING_PROPERTIES%3D1%26TRANSPILE%3D1%26CHECK_TYPES%3D1%26CLOSURE_PASS%3D1%26PRESERVE_TYPE_ANNOTATIONS%3D1%26PRETTY_PRINT%3D1).

**Application Code**

```
const Mocha = /** @type {!MochaJS} */ (require('mocha'));

const mochaInstance = new Mocha();
const Suite = Mocha.Suite;
```

**Closure Externs**

```
/** @constructor */
const MochaJS = function() {};

/** @type {!MochaJS.Suite} */
MochaJS.prototype.Suite;

/** @record */
MochaJS.Suite = function() {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty comes because Closure-compiler doesn't handle external module definitions well. Also, dont' confuse the constructor/namespace with an instance. They are different.

**Application**

```
// A constructor type for Mocha
const Mocha = /** @type {!function(new:MochaJS)} */ (require('mocha'));
const mochaInstance = new Mocha();

const Suite = /** @type {!MochaJSSuite} */ (Mocha.Suite);
```

**Externs**

```
/** @constructor */
const MochaJS = function() {};

/** @function */
MochaJSSuite = function() {};
```

This is just rough guesses for the types - I'm not familiar enough with Mocha to write the externs without going to hunt down the documentation reference. Hopefully it will point you in the right direction though.